# How to set ingress-nginx custom errors

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I use the kubernetes ingress-nginx controller and a set custom errors on GKE but I have some problems.

Goal:
If a 50x error occurs in `something-web-app`, I'll return the HTTP status code 200 and JSON `{"status":200, "message":"ok"}`

Problems:

1. I have read the [custom-errors document](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-errors/) but there is no example of how to customize the `default-backend`.
2. I do not understand the difference between ConfigMap and Annotation.
3. How does ingress-nginx controller work in the first place.

Comment: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: nginx-errors-svc` # This is referencing the SAME NAMESPACE that this resource is in `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: 404,503` try this 2 annotation

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using two way :

1. Adding annotation in ingress
2. Change in ingress controller configmap (which is more like beckend)

**1**. Try adding this annotation to kubernetes ingress :

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: nginx-errors-svc
>
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-http-errors: 404,503
>
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/default-backend: error-pages

If that doesn't work add this along with two :

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location @custom_503 {
        return 404;
      }
      error_page 503 @custom_503;
```

**2.** Configmap editing

You can apply this config map to ingress controller

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
name: nginx-configuration-ext
data:
  custom-http-errors: 502,503,504
  proxy-next-upstream-tries: "2"
  server-tokens: "false"
```

You can also refer this blog : https://habr.com/ru/company/flant/blog/445596/